# Вылетание картинки при клике на объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть кликабельный объект.Я сделал родительский объект и дочерний объект ,который появляется каждый раз когда нажимаешь на объект.Но каким способом можно сделать так,чтобы картинка вылетала по рандомному вектору?

```
private bool move;
private Vector2 randomVector;

private void Update() {
    if (!move) return;
    transform.Translate(randomVector * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void StartMotion() {
    transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero;
    randomVector = new Vector2 (UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300 , 250) , UnityEngine.Random.Range(-350, 0));
    move = true;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.